# Is this a libc++ bug?

Tags: c++, libc++

The function `std::char_traits::copy` is implemented in `libc++` like this:

```
template <class _CharT>
inline _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR_AFTER_CXX17
_CharT*
char_traits<_CharT>::copy(char_type* __s1, const char_type* __s2, size_t __n)
{
    if (!__libcpp_is_constant_evaluated()) {
        _LIBCPP_ASSERT(__s2 < __s1 || __s2 >= __s1+__n, "char_traits::copy overlapped range");
    }
    char_type* __r = __s1;
    for (; __n; --__n, ++__s1, ++__s2)
        assign(*__s1, *__s2);
    return __r;
}
```

The condition in `_LIBCPP_ASSERT` seems backwards. Shouldn't it be

```
__s1 < __s2 || __s1 >= __s2+__n
```

What am I missing?

Comment: @273K it is actually like `memcpy` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/copy

Comment: The ranges are not allowed to overlap at either end according to the requirements in https://eel.is/c++draft/char.traits.require#tab:char.traits.req. So I feel it should check both directions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before resolution of [LWG issue 3085](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#3085) (targeting C++23) the check made in the shown code is actually the only precondition specified for `char_traits::copy`. The beginning of the source range may not lie in the destination range, but the beginning of the destination range may lie in the source range.

However, then the implementation in the shown code would be wrong. Copying from beginning to end in a loop will potentially overwrite source elements too early.

The resolution of the LWG issue makes the precondition stricter to require source and destination range to not overlap at all. Apparently multiple implementations had not considered the previously-allowed overlap correctly in their implementation.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a bug, libc++ condition until C++23 is correct. [std::char_traits::copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/copy):

> The behavior is undefined if copied character ranges overlap, i.e. `src` is in `[dest, dest + count)`.

Bad: `(src >= dest && src < dest + count)`

Assert: `!(src >= dest && src < dest + count)` -> `!(src >= dest) || !(src < dest + count)` -> `(src < dest) || (src >= dest + count)` -> `__s2 < __s1 || __s2 >= __s1 + __n`.

---

The mathematical logic rule applied here: *!(a && b)* is *!a || !b*.

Comment: `src < dest` is exactly [the wrong thing to check](https://godbolt.org/z/ecxdxaKG3)

Comment: "The behavior is undefined if copied character ranges overlap, i.e. src is in [dest, dest + count)." **It is a bug in cppreference**. "Ranges overlap" is not equivalent to "src is in [dest, dest + count)". The standard lists the correct condition.

Comment: Might be a defect in the standard and fixed in the draft. What libc++ sources are you looking at?

Comment: @heapunderrun This is not the standard, it's a public draft. And that assertion is outside the standard, LLVM just made it for optional diagnostics. GNU libstdc++ does not have assertions: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-api-4.5/a00783_source.html

Comment: You are right, looks like a bug in C++11-20, fixed in C++23 draft.

Comment: @n.m. Good point! I just looked at the actual LVVM sources, that code in the question is deprecated: `_LIBCPP_DEPRECATED_("char_traits<T> for T not equal to char, wchar_t, char8_t, char16_t or char32_t is non-standard and is provided for a temporary period. It will be removed in LLVM 18, so please migrate off of it.")`. The actual code uses `std::copy_n()`.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug *in the C++ standard*. Libc++ just faithfully reproduces it.

Versions from C++11 to C++20 [list the nonsensical requirement](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/char.traits.require#tab:char.traits.req) that the *source* is not inside the *destination range*.

```
X::copy(s,p,n) ... Preconditions: p not in [s,s+n)
```

The intent is, and always have been, that the source range and the destination range do not overlap. This is fixed in the [C++23 draft](https://eel.is/c++draft/strings#char.traits.require):

```
X::copy(s,p,n) ... Preconditions: The ranges [p, p+n) and [s, s+n) do not overlap.
```

Comment: It is not quite faithful. If it was supposed to be faithful to the wording, they would have needed to do the copy backwards to take care of the allowed overlap. So I still think the choice they made is a bit weird if it was intentional.